# MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() has system dependent offset

Tags: android, media-player

I'm using the `android.media.MediaPlayer` to play a song in my Android application.
Some events in my app are triggered at certain parts of the song.
To know where in the song I am right now I use `MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()`.

A problem with this approach is that `getCurrentPosition()` returns the current position in the song, plus a small error. The error is **constant**, but different for all phones I tested.
The error also changes when updating Android.
The error ranges from -50 to 150 ms.

Is this a known problem?
Any ideas on how to work around it? (Except creating a table over all known phones and android versions)

Comment: Are there any co-relation with Android OS versions?

Comment: Yes, but it is unclear if this is the only source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known problem. See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11590
And as of today, I have not seen any good solutions.